# How to execute sql query to match column value which contains single quote(')

Tags: c#, sql-server, syntax-error, sqldatareader, single-quotes

My C# code to find a data row with column name CustomerAccountNumber which contains a value KKL'M"/ (single quote ' in value) return nothing

here is my C# code:

```
matchingid = "KKL'M\"/";
bool foundCustomer = false;
SqlConnection cnn;
connetionString = "Server=" + config.serverName + ";Database=" + config.companyName + ";Trusted_Connection=true";
cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
cnn.Open();

var queryString = "SELECT CustomerAccountNumber, CustomerAccountName FROM [" + config.companyName + "].[dbo].[SLCustomerAccount] WHERE CustomerAccountNumber = @matchingAccountName";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, cnn);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@matchingAccountName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar) { Value = matchingid });
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       foundCustomer = true;
    }
}
cnn.Close();
```

screenshot of the database where value contains
[image]

Comment: That's a weird looking number... You should parameterize your query.

Comment: That is easy, just use parameters in stead of building the query like this. You can read all about them [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/ADOQuery_(Delphi)) and it will also protect you from sql injection, which could be a problem if you build your queries in code like your sample

Comment: @HoneyBadger Can you paramerterize the database name in a query on SQL Server?

Comment: @NicholasHunter, the problem isn't the database name, it's already enclosed in square brackets

Comment: @HoneyBadger right gotcha my bad

Comment: Stop bad habits. Your connection should determine the database to use for your object references. You should NOT use 3 part names without a very good reason.

Comment: 3 part names is getting depricated anyway, see [this](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/)

Comment: @GuidoG only for column references, not for table references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameters instead of constructing your query like that, and also put all objects that are disposable in a `using`.

This example can get you on the correct way

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
{
    cnn.Open();

    var queryString = "SELECT CustomerAccountNumber, CustomerAccountName FROM dbo.SLCustomerAccount WHERE CustomerAccountNumber = @matchingid";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, cnn))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@matchingID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = matchingID;  // specify correct length

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 foundCustomer = true;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments, you cant parameterize the company name, but it is not needed in your query so just leave it out.
The use of 3 part names will get deprecated, read all about that [here](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/)

I would also like to mention that by using parameters, you don't have to worry about sql injection anymore. Not sure if your case has a problem with that, but it's best to always use parameters because you never have problems with formats, quotes `'`, and whatever you can find in your values, and you be safe against sql injection

**EDIT 2**

As also mentioned by @NicholasHunter, be careful with

```
matchingid = "kkl'm\"/n";
```

If a string can contain special characters, you can either escape them all, or simply use this

```
matchingid = @"kkl'm\"/n";
```

Comment: You can't parametrize the company name, as that is an object name, not a value.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes that is right, but as HoneyBadger mentioned it is not needed to specify it at all. Edited my answer

Comment: thanks @GuidoG that resolved the issue. :)

Comment: @GuidoG i noticed that its byepass the catch error but its not finding the valud with  single quote its skipping the single quote and find a same value which doesn't have single quote, kklm\"/

Comment: @HarishKumar can you edit your question, and show me the code you are trying now. Maybe I can see what is going on then

Comment: @GuidoG i have modified the question and edit the code which you suggested, can you please see it now

Comment: Specify varchar length also

Comment: matchingID.ToString() did the trick in command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@matchingID", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = matchingID });
@GuidoG

Comment: @HarishKumar OK, glad you resolved the issue

Comment: @Charlieface Is it possible to specify varchar length when creating SqlCommand parameters ? I never do that and  never had a problem yet

Comment: `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@matchingID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) { Value = matchingID });` or better `command.Parameters.Add("@matchingID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = matchingID;` see also https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/